# Firebase/Android FirebaseUI Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build an application in Android and I tried using the [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), but I am getting this error:

error: cannot access zzeuq
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuq not found

Here is my gradle [file.](https://pastebin.com/YUUUjGH9)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vanillatalk.vanillatalk"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I think that the error is related to missmatched versions of firebase, since it 11.6.0 and firebase-ui-database:4.0.0, but I cannot seem to find the correct versions for the firebase-ui-database that would match the 11.6.0?

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `version 4.0` of `firebase ui` you need to update firebase [dependencies](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

For version `11.6.0` of firebase you should use version `3.x.x` of Firebase UI, see [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/48c625b4e9556376481aac0cb9541f90ad8b6d4c#dependencies).

Comment: At version 3.0.0 for firebase ui, i am getting this error "Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}". It does not seem to work, and the next version is for 11.8.0

Comment: I recommend you to use the most up to date version :)

Comment: I tried changing to change the firebase versions to:     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1', but I only get this error: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your gms plugin version? It's in the other build.gradle file :)

Comment: Also firebase.core latest version is 16.0.0, so you should replace that as well

Comment: This is my gms "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'"

Comment: Try as well updating the gms to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have to use all latest library dependency to use

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
```

Now I checked that when I use `firebase-database:15.0.1` library it's doesn't let me do syn properly.

Use the latest version of all other library dependency, I'm it will be work.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

Or you can try to find `firebase-database:11.6.0` this version similar `FirebaseUi` library. But it's hard to found.

Thanks.